# Does an E2 visa allow someone to work in the US unrestricted

Tags: united-states, employment, visa

I have an E2 Visa for the USA, this has a named company on it. What I’m unclear about is - does this allow me to work in the US for anyone? Or does it restrict me specifically to that company.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=E2+Visa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Code of Federal Regulations, [8 CFR 274a.12(b)(5)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/274a.12#b_5):

> **(b) Aliens authorized for employment with a specific employer incident to status or parole.** The following classes of aliens are authorized to be employed in the United States by the specific employer and subject to any restrictions described in the section(s) of this chapter indicated as a condition of their parole or of their admission in, or subsequent change to, the designated nonimmigrant classification. An alien in one of these classes is not issued an employment authorization document by DHS:
>
> ...
>
> (5) A nonimmigrant treaty trader (E-1) or treaty investor (E-2), pursuant to § 214.2(e) of this chapter. An alien in this status may be employed only by the treaty-qualifying company through which the alien attained the status. Employment authorization does not extend to the dependents of the principal treaty trader or treaty investor (also designated “E-1” or “E-2”), other than those specified in paragraph (c)(2) of this section;

Your E-2 status permits you to work only for the named company.